# Laravel job not deserializing model

Tags: laravel, serialization, model, jobs

I have set up Redis to proccess jobs of my Laravel 5.8 app. Basic jobs like send email of contact form works fine, since it only accepts Request as input parameter.

Now when I try to run a job with model as input parameter the **handle() method doesnt load model from database** and `null` is given to Mail contructor.

**Horizon:**
[image]

**Exception:**

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Argument 1 passed to App\Mail\OrderCreatedMail::__construct() must be an instance of App\Order, null given, called in /mnt/d/Weby/fts/app/Jobs/SendOrderMailJob.php on line 28 in /mnt/d/Weby/fts/app/Mail/OrderCreatedMail.php:16
```

**Data:**

```
{
objOrder: {
class: "App\Order",
id: 29,
relations: [
],
connection: "mysql"
},
job: null,
connection: null,
queue: null,
chainConnection: null,
chainQueue: null,
delay: null,
chained: [
]
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$objOrder = Order::create($objRequest->all());
SendOrderMailJob::dispatch($objOrder);
```

**Job:**

```
class SendOrderMailJob implements ShouldQueue {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $objOrder;

    public function __construct(Order $objOrder) {
        $this->objOrder = $objOrder;
    }    

    public function handle() {
        Mail::to($this->objOrder->email)->send(new OrderCreatedMail($this->objOrder));
    }
}
```

**Mail:**

```
class OrderCreatedMail extends Mailable {
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $objOrder;

    public function __construct(Order $objOrder) {
        $this->objOrder = $objOrder;
    }

    public function build() {
        return $this->from('MY_MAIL')
            ->replyTo('MY_MAIL')
            ->subject('MY_SUBJECT')
            ->markdown('emails/orders/created');
    }
}
```

Comment: try calling `$objOrder->fresh()` before passing it for dispatch, I've had this issue before with `::create`

Comment: Didnt help, same problem.

Answer (score -1):

`composer dump-autoload` fixed this problem. But I have no idea why...